# TeX Live 2017 onwards Using $TEXMFAUXTREES are there disadvantages

Tags: texmf

I mainly use MiKTeX (Windows) as its simpler/lighter for portable use. TeX Live 2017 introduced $TEXMFAUXTREES similar for my usage in MiKTeX to the assignment on the fly of user-roots.

Although my usage is portable I use the same techniques on full installs.

For Example prior to entering MiKTeX-Console I can call
  `initexmf --user-roots=%~d0\mytexmf --update-fndb=%~d0\mytexmf --update-fndb`
     or as recommended below by Ulrike Fischer `initexmf --register-root=%~d0\mytexmf`

Equally on TeX Live since 2017 I can use `tlmgr conf auxtrees add =%~d0\mytexmf` and running `kpsewhich -expand-var=$texmf-local` confirms it is first in the list, such that when I have a local version of a TeX Live package it is my local .sty that is used in preference to the standard one, same as it is in MiKTeX. In this way I only need to maintain one common set for any engine.

All well and good so I can use \mytexmf with any system.

My question is are there any known issues with this mixed approach ?

Comment: No. I'm using lots of root with both systems without any problems. But I would add a root in miktex with `initexmf --register-root=....` . This updates the fndb directly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for the tip, am I right to presume TeX Live does not need any form of texhash or similar with this usage ?